# how to correctly get ID?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, sfdoctrineguard

I use Symfony 1.4, Doctrine 1.2 and sfDoctrineGuardPlugin. In actions.class.php i have:

```
$this->idsfguard = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId();
```

if i am logged in this work good, but if i logout then i have error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   getId() on a non-object in

I tried:

```
  if ($this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->isAuthenticated()){
    $this->idsfguard = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId();
  }
```

but i have error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   isAuthenticated() on a non-object in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($this->getUser()->isAuthenticated()) {
  $id = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId();
}
```

The `isAuthenticated()` method is for the sfUser class, not sfGuardUser. And you can only access the sfGuardUser class via sfUser if the user is authenticated.

Comment: thanks! now in template Success i should use isset($id) same as in clear php? in symfony to do it differently?

Comment: @Beyed Black: isset() is fine. Just make sure you pass the variable to the template as "$this->id", and you can then do isset($id).